# acceptance testing Java OpenGL applications

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, acceptance-testing

I have a Java desktop application that has a major component of it written using Java OpenGL (JOGL). When it comes to writing automated acceptance tests for this, I'm not really sure how to write them without being very brittle. With Swing (and HTML) objects, you can get handles to fields/objects (using a variety of acceptance test platforms - Selenium, Rational, etc).

Since OpenGL is a lot of just rendering and working less with objects, I'm not sure how to really test, for example, that the screen is showing what I expect without doing some screen scraping.

Has anyone worked on acceptance testing an app like this and can provide any pointers or tools to help?

Answer (score 0):

Taking screen captures wont get you far, since different graphic cards will produce slightly different images, so pixel-by-pixel comparison will fail when run on another machine.

The following can vary among different cards:
- texture filtering
- floating point accuracy in shaders.
- anti-aliasing implementation
- various driver-specific optimizations.

As far as I know, automated testing for 3d graphics applications is an unsolved problem to date.